# Jruby code to truncate a table with snowflake

Tags: ruby, jruby

This is the code I am using to connect to the snowflake database:

```ruby
require 'java'
require 'rubygems'
require 'C:/Program Files/CData/CData JDBC Driver for Snowflake 2018/lib/cdata.jdbc.snowflake.jar'

url = "jdbc:snowflake:User=Admin;Password=test123;Server=localhost;Database=Northwind;Warehouse=TestWarehouse;Account=Tester1;"
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url)
stmt = conn.createStatement
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Id, ProductName FROM Products")
while (rs.next) do
  puts rs.getString(1) + ' ' + rs.getString(2)
end
```

But I need to run other SQL queries as well:

- sql_query1: `Copy into table1 from table2`
- sql_query2: `Truncate table student`

How can I run these queries using my code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would just update your sql

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Id, ProductName FROM Products")
```

Change that sql to something other than the example you found.